# Tradeoffs between wind turbines and tethered kites for offshore wind power? How to decide which is better for a given site?

Tags: wind-power, economics

[Wind turbines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_turbine) are a mature technology for offshore harvesting of wind power. They can manage themselves in variable wind speed and shut down safely when it gets too strong. The largest systems have blade lengths of 80 to 120 meters (even longer are being explored) with maximum power of 8 to 12 MW or more.

Since blades need to be replaced from time to time, there is now work to make them from materials more suitable for recycling or reuse.

[Tethered or crosswind kites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosswind_kite_power) are still in the development stage. Since they "fly" they can reach higher up where winds may be stronger and steadier. Some use work done by kite on the tether (reeling in and out) others put propellors and generators on the kites themselves and end up looking a lot like multi-prop airplanes. They have the potential to be lighter and cheaper per unit, but without long term demonstration at scale it may be difficult to compare them directly to wind turbines.

No matter, I'd like to ask anyway:

**Question:** What are the tradeoffs between wind turbines and tethered kites for offshore wind power? For a given site how would one know which is likely to be better? For example, will one be cheaper per square km of "wind farm area" while the other cheaper per MW?

Potentially helpful:

- [Makani; Harnessing wind energy with kites to create renewable electricity](https://x.company/projects/makani/)
- BBC Future Planet's [The kites seeking the world's surest winds](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20220309-the-kites-flying-to-harness-the-worlds-strongest-winds) (source of image below)

[image: Ground-tethered kites have the potential to reach higher than conventional turbines, to access strong, reliable winds (Credit: SkySails Group)]

> Ground-tethered kites have the potential to reach higher than conventional turbines, to access strong, reliable winds (Credit: SkySails Group)

Comment: The other metric that would be useful would be, which would give a higher MW per square kilometer & even maximum MW per device: kite or wind turbine. The picture in the question shows a key difference between the two. Wind turbines occupy a specific area of land & they need to be positioned so they don't interfere with one another. I get the impression that due to the length of the tether & the 3D movement of kites, each kite may occupy a larger area of land than a wind a turbine.

Comment: I haven't heard of offshore kites being explored. To my knowledge kites are mostly of interest when it comes to temporary, small scale energy production, while wind farms are a huge, long term investment.

Comment: Makani were very interested in offshore kites. The big advantage is that areal density was less of an issue and the lower torque meant smaller platforms. Plus no-one cared if they dropped one in the sea 5km from their tower, but people get excited on land. End of doco is all about the water option: https://youtu.be/qd_hEja6bzE?t=4624

Comment: The problem with fabric kites is durability, it's just hard to make lightweight, flexible, durable fabrics. Makani went with a solid glider for that reason. They also put the generator into the kite since they needed a motor to launch it. The fabric setups tend to use the winch motor as the generator AFAIK, which means it's on the ground but also harder to launch and recover. FWIW I've got no ties to Makani, I know a couple of the people but they know I think it's a stupid idea, but because I know them I know more about that project than other kite generators.

Comment: The brutal answer is: wind turbines. They actually work, kites don't. Kites might work in the future, but in the next decade they're not going to be able to be deployed at any useful scale.

Comment: @Móż certainly "kites don't work" would be a great answer if it can be supported, but it seems too soon for that to be bourn out conclusively. Perhaps this question can't be currently answered in a *Stack Exchange* way?

Comment: It can't be answered because you're asking us to document a negative. The answer "there is no commercial off the shelf kite power at useful scale" is purely opinion. Me not being able to find any evidence that such a thing exists might be down to my limited knowledge and skills. You're asking one question "how resource intensive are kite-based wind farms?" when no-one can point to such a thing existing, so underneath your question is "can anyone find a kite-based wind farm that is producing electricity". Until we find that person any question about resource intensity  of one is unanswerable.

Comment: If your question is actually "in theory, could kite based electricity generation work at at the GW scale?" then I reckon you should close this question and ask that instead.

Comment: @Móż well in that case I can adjust the question to make it more answerable or delete it. I'm happy with either, do you have any thoughts on how it could be salvaged? Your comments are certainly valuable and I find them interesting, perhaps something along the line of "How far away are kites from full-scale demonstrations?" (oh, I forgot about closing, I'd rather just delete than have a bad closed question record. Since I've only got 3 other questions it would be 25%)

Comment: That's also unanswerable, like "how far away is fusion power" where the answer is "[30 years, always 30 years](https://www.discovermagazine.com/technology/why-nuclear-fusion-is-always-30-years-away)". While we're still in the research phase all we can really say is that some experiements show promise and let's hope. I'm not sure how to rescue your question but I kind of like having the topic at least mentioned here. It's kind of suggestive that Google couldn't make it work, with their budget, and the folk I know from Makani have all gone into completely different areas

Comment: @Móż Okay well I don't see any dramatic harm to the site leaving it here for another 24 hours to give it some further thought on what to do next. *Thanks for your help and input!*

Comment: @Móż or another 16,000 hours for that matter :-) I just read through (quickly) IEEE Spectrums January 17, 2024 [Flying Kites Deliver Container-Size Power Generation; Automated wind-energy system brings portable renewables off-grid](https://spectrum.ieee.org/micro-wind-power-kitepower) and it helps to get a feel for what might actually work in the near future - something small and portable for remote locations where building a tower might not be an option.